# useLazyQuery returns old data after clearStore or resetStore

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I have a problem with the apollo client, I want to log out the user from my app and when logging him out I want to remove all the data, but right now the clearStore doesn't clear the `data` object from useLazyQuery.

```js
const client = useApolloClient();
const [getMe, { loading, error, data }] = useLazyQuery(q, {
  fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
});
React.useEffect(() => {
    getMe();
  }, [isLoggedIn, getMe]);

const onRefresh = async () => {
    dispatch(logout());
    await client.clearStore();
    console.log(data);
  };
```

console.log(data) data returns always `{"me": {"__typename": "User", "email": "xxx.xxx@gmail.com"}}`

It always returns old data, even after running the logout function several times without reloading the app, even when the API response is [Error: Unauthorized]. it is still holding old data in it

I'm using apollo 3.7.0
expo 46.0.16
react-native 0.69.6
react 18.0.0

Thanks for help.